# grep -c "string" file.txt if "string" continues on next line?

Tags: grep, c

As the title says, I am trying to count the instances of a string in a text file. However, in some instances, the string continues onto the next line. How can I alter this simple code to find the instances of "string" even if it happens to be split by a new line?

`grep -c "string" file.txt`[image]

Comment: `string` cannot continue onto a new line. Can you update your question to show an example of what you mean?

Comment: (Added a screenshot for specifics) For instance, the grep -c "FQTLLALH" command returns a number of instances. But, if I extend the string to search for "FQTLLALHR", the current code/command fails to count the instance iff "R" occurs on the next line.

Comment: Sorry, can't read a screenshot. Please use formatting to show. And put your explanation in the question too - comments can be missed or even deleted

Comment: And is that the entire file or are you perhaps working with protein sequences in fasta format so you also have a line with `>protein name` and can have many lines like that in the file? This sort of details is very important. Maybe you can use the FastaToTbl script I have [posted here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/2651/298) to convert to a one-seq-per-line format that is more easily greppable?

Comment: Thank you for all the input! I was working with protein sequences in fasta format. I ended up doing something very similar to the accepted answer. Another route: awk '/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n",$0);next; } { printf("%s",$0);}  END {printf("\n");}' < file.txt > new_file.txt       This would create a new text file with all sequences in a single line. Then follow title of question or simply ctrl+f the sequence in a text editor.

Comment: If you arrived at a solution that worked better than any given answer, you should unaccepted the answer that you did not actually make use of, then add your own answer as a proper answer (not an edit to the question), then accept that answer.  I have reverted your edit adding an answer as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to:

1. combine the whole file into one string by removing line feed
2. split the string into multiple lines by the pattern `FQTLLALHR`
3. count the lines of the result:

```
tr -d "\n\r" <file.txt | sed -e "s/FQTLLALHR/\n/g" | wc -l
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

I was working with protein sequences in fasta format. An entry begins with ">protein_name" and is followed by a new line. This line begins the sequence of letters (amino acids) which occupy 60 characters per line before continuing onto a new line. To maintain a similar format, but have each sequence between ">protein_name" on a single line, I followed:

```
awk '/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n",$0);next; } { printf("%s",$0);} END {printf("\n");}' < file.txt > new_file.txt
```

This would create a new text file in the current directory which has all sequences in a single line. I could then open the text file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> the sequence to count occurrences, or perform:

```
grep -c "string" new_file.txt
```